# Based on If condition I want make the field as required in angular2

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

```
 <div *ngFor="let proc of procInputList" >
         <label >{{proc.key_ | Capitalize}}</label>
   <input id="{{proc.key_}}" name="inputparams" type ="text" class="form-control" required = "proc.r_q == Y ? required :none"  />
</div>
```

But unfortunately its not working for me..and I don't want to use forms there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To condition an attibute you can:

```
<input class="form-control" [required] = "proc.r_q == 'Y'"  />
```